# highlight td or tr next to this

Tags: javascript, jquery

what's the best way to change the background color of rowXcol2 when the checkbox is clicked?

```
<table>
<tr><td>row1col1</td><td>row1col2</td><td><input class="actionItem" type="checkbox" /></td></td></tr>
<tr><td>row2col1</td><td>row2col2</td><td><input class="actionItem" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>row3col1</td><td>row3col2</td><td><input class="actionItem" type="checkbox" /></td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("tr :checkbox").live("click", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", this.checked ? "red" : "");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(".actionItem").click(function() {
  var highlight_td = $(this).parent().prev("td");
  highlight_td.css({background-color: "#ff0"});  
});
```